# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, ipython

Installing Caffe for Ubuntu 16.04 with this [Install Guide](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide).

When I run:

> for req in $(cat requirements.txt); do pip install $req; done

I get:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-build-SkgwMK/ipython/

What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: You're only showing the last line of the error message, the actual error should be a few lines earlier.

Comment: That for-loop can also be replaced by `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Not sure why they do it like that.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975523/pipinstall-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1).

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `python-setuptools` and `python-dev` first. To do so, open a terminal and type:

> sudo apt-get install python-setuptools & python-dev -y