# pip install gives "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install python package `rpy2` with pip install on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
pip install rpy2==2.2.7
```

but get error message (see full output below):

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EuOI6K/unroll/
```

The same thing happens with other packages, like `pip install unroll`, or using `pip2`. I thought this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881687/what-does-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1-mean?noredirect=1#comment1564233_881687) was the same issue, but there it gets resolved by using sudo.

#### Solutions tried

I tried solutions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c), like: `pip install --upgrade setuptools`, `(sudo) easy_install -U setuptools`, or `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`, but to no avail.

#### python/pip info

Someone suggested I might have a weird python/pip installation, here are a few infos:

```
sudo which python pip pip2 | xargs -rd '\n' readlink -f 
/usr/bin/python2.7   
/usr/local/bin/pip  
/usr/local/bin/pip2  

sudo python --version   
Python 2.7.12  

sudo pip --version  
pip 9.0.1 from /home/matifou/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)  
/usr/bin/pip2 --version  
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

ls -l $(which pip); dpkg -S /usr/bin/pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 204 Nov  8 16:24 /usr/local/bin/pip
python-pip: /usr/bin/pip
```

#### Full error output

```
pip install rpy2==2.2.7  
Collecting rpy2==2.2.7   Using cached rpy2-2.2.7.tar.gz  
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/tmp/pip-build-EkrbmM/rpy2/setup.py", line 462, in 
        [os.path.join('doc', 'source', 'rpy2_logo.png')])],
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py",
line 280, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py",
line 295, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py",
line 526, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py",
line 562, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py",
line 36, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_ext()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py",
line 119, in _add_defaults_ext
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-EkrbmM/rpy2/setup.py", line 155, in finalize_options
        config += get_rconfig(r_home, about)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-EkrbmM/rpy2/setup.py", line 319, in get_rconfig
        rc = RConfig.from_string(rconfig, allow_empty = allow_empty)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-EkrbmM/rpy2/setup.py", line 279, in from_string
        + '\nin string\n' + string)
    ValueError: Invalid substring
    -fopenmp
    in string
    -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EkrbmM/rpy2/

pip install unroll
Collecting unroll   Using cached unroll-0.1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/tmp/pip-build-QimGjp/unroll/setup.py", line 2, in 
        ez_setup.use_setuptools()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ez_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
        return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ez_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
        to_dir, download_delay)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ez_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
        src = urlopen(url)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in tmp/pip-
build-QimGjp/unroll/
```

Comment: Is R already installed?

Comment: Try running it with the `-H` flag like `sudo -H`

Comment: Sorry but this is too messy for me to feel like helping someone untangle it at the moment. Even with the bounty. Thanks for your reminders though.

Comment: Thanks @George, but unfortunately even sith the `sudo -H` it does not work :-(

Answer (score 6):

## Upgrade `setuptools` using `pip`

The version of `python-setuptools` in the package repository of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is **out-of-date / unmaintained.**
Upgrade it with `pip` instead of relying on the package manager:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: This solved my issue with in bionic, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Updating `setuptools` did not resolve my issue.  However, telling pip to upgrade itself did.

The following command resolved my issue (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33680205/2849019))

```bsh
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thanks, upgrading `setuptools` also did not work for me. But upgrading `pip` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution I took for my own question: the answers proposed did not solve the issue, so I ended up using `conda`, creating a specific environment for the package I needed, and this worked! This is not the best solution, especially as it requires to install a parallel version (thou one can use miniconda for space) but is a practical one!

Answer (score 0):

you need to get setup tools and probably dev modules type the following

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

it may make sense to upgrade pip first to ensure there's nothing but smooth running this is done by typing

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

good luck

Comment: Thanks. But I actually already have these three installed, to their newest version...